# Add search functionality in list view

Tags: android

This is implementation of List where all contact are Listed.
I want to know how can I implement search functionality on this.

1] MainActivity[CustomerList.java]

```
public class CustomerList extends Activity {


private String TAG = CustomerList.class.getSimpleName();

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

EditText search_item;

private ListView listView;

// ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllCustomers;

static  String CUSTOMER_ID= "customer_id";
static  String CUSTOMER_CONTACT_NUMBER="customer_contact_number";
static  String CUSTOMER_NAME="customer_name";
static  String ZONE="zone";
static  String CUSTOMER_EMAIL="customer_email";



private static String url = "http://103.229.245.235/cb.selectnetworks.in/getAllCustomers";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);



    getAllCustomers = new ArrayList<>();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCustomerList);

    search_item=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextSearch);

    new GetCustomerData().execute();
}


public class GetCustomerData extends AsyncTask<URL, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(CustomerList.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("please wait");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        getAllCustomers= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        HttpHandler httpHandler= new HttpHandler();
        String jsonStr=httpHandler.makeServiceCall(url);
        Log.e(TAG,"Response from url: " +jsonStr);

        if(jsonStr !=null){
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONArray arr= jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){

                    JSONObject obj = arr.optJSONObject(i);// (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                    String customer_id  = obj.getString("customer_id");
                    String customer_name = obj.getString("customer_name");
                    String customer_contact_number = obj.getString("customer_contact_number");
                    String zone = obj.getString("zone_id");
                    String customer_email = obj.getString("customer_email");

//                        Toast.makeText(CustomerList.this,customer_id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    HashMap<String,String> customData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    customData.put("customer_id",customer_id);
                    customData.put("customer_name",customer_name);
                    customData.put("customer_contact_number",customer_contact_number);
                    customData.put("zone",zone);
                    customData.put("customer_email",customer_email);

                    getAllCustomers.add(customData);

                }

            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"json parsing error: "  + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"json error : " + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e(TAG,"json data :" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if(progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListViewCustomerList);

      //  Toast.makeText(CustomerList.this,getAllCustomers.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        final ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                CustomerList.this,getAllCustomers,R.layout.activity_listviewitem,new String[]{"customer_id","customer_name",
                "customer_contact_number", "zone","customer_email"}, new int[] 

{R.id.TextViewcustomer_id,R.id.TextVIewcustomer_name,R.id.TextViewcustomer_mobile,R.id.TextViewcustomer_zone,R.id.TextViewcustomer_email});
                       listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);



          /*  listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(CustomerList.this,getAllCustomers,R.layout.activity_listviewitem,new String[]
                    {"customer_id", "customer_name","customer_contact_number","zone"},
                     new int[] {R.id.TextViewcustomer_id,R.id.TextVIewcustomer_name,
                                R.id.TextViewcustomer_mobile,R.id.TextViewcustomer_zone});

            listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter); */



            // Search Functionality

            search_item.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {



                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {






                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    String text= search_item.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());


                }
            });

                    }





    }
}
```

2] HttpHandler class

```
public class HttpHandler {

    public static final String TAG= HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    public HttpHandler(){

    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl){

        String response=null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

3] Activity_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:hint="Search Items"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/EditTextSearch"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListViewCustomerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

4] Listviewitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="Customer Id"
        android:id="@+id/TextViewcustomer_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="14sp"
       />/ android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Customer Name"
        android:id="@+id/TextVIewcustomer_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
      />//  android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Customer Mno"
        android:id="@+id/TextViewcustomer_mobile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Customer Zone"
        android:id="@+id/TextViewcustomer_zone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Customer Email"
        android:id="@+id/TextViewcustomer_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so you want us to add that functionality in your code?

Comment: nice code! (not really.) Please take some time to describe the problem, adn what you have done to solve it so far.

Comment: `String text= search_item.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());` is not enought to add search functionality

Answer (score 0):

try to add textchange listener to your search filter textfield

```
search_item.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // When user changed the Text
        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
    }
});
```

check this for full example : [search in listview](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/)

[link2](http://www.androprogrammer.com/2014/02/add-searching-in-list-view.html)